# How to create a nav bar like Apple?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I create navigation bar like Apple has? I have given it a try and here is what I have so far: [image]

As you can see, the spacing of the buttons are a bit off. I used `justify-content: space-around` to achieve this. I have tried to make the spacing the same like the Apple website but have not been successful and was wondering if anyone can help me. Just for a reference, here is the navigation bar of the Apple website.

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  height: 44px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #323232;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #B8B8B8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-houzz"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `body{margin:0px}`

Comment: `0` is unitless, so `0px` is unnecessary.... but that won't solve the problem.

Comment: Why can't use just copy / paste the style from Apple?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Already did that, forgot to include it. But does not solve my problem I'm afraid.

Comment: @OmarDajani, please check the answer and it's exactly what you are looking for larger screens. For smaller screens you will need to add media queries and also need to use something similar to [navbar-collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add an additional wrapper to `ul` let's say "appleNav"

Add properties of the following to `appleNav`

```
.appleNav {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 44px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #323232;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #B8B8B8;
}

.appleNav {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="appleNav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/apple-xxl.png" height="20"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/search-3-xxl.png" height="20"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha! That did the trick! Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! But what if I wanted to change the space between each button?

Comment: you can customise it by selecting that particular button. Please check [nth-child select](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp). You should use something like `li:nth-child(4)`.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

1. Apple applies a "container" with a "max width" the the nav.  That has been added below.
2. I've adjusted some styling to improve the look / feel.  Comments in the CSS below.
3. If you look carefully, apple has "dead space" between links.  That exists in this markup / layout as well.

**If this does not solve your problem**, then please advise what you mean by "the spacing is off" - be specific *and clear*, otherwise it's impossible to help.... :)

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  height: 44px;
  background: #323232;
  text-align: center; /* to center the UL in the nav */
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px; /* change to desired width */
  /* removed height from here, apply to a elements */
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto; /* 0 auto allows it to self-center in the nav */
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px; /* apply the height here, pushes the li / ul to be the correct height */
  line-height: 44px; /* to get vertical centering */
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #B8B8B8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-houzz"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. You partially answered my question. I would like the buttons to be centered in the nav bar and have equal spacing on both the right and the left side of the bar. Or in other words, I would like space on both the right and the left side of the bar and the buttons to be centered. I would also like to be able to alter the space between the buttons and have them equally spaced. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: 1. To manage the widths (which will affect spacing) for the individual buttons, Apple actually applies specific widths to the elements.  2. In a wider screen, the spacing from left edge of screen (and right edge of screen) to left edge of nav (and right edge of nav) is equal ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a space between each button and a button you have to use the margin command to make a break and a distance between all the buttons equally. Position `margin` before the button you want to make an equal distance between it and the remaining buttons and then define it within the style setting the distance you want between each button and Use the `margin` command and select the direction you want to set the distance between and the other button if left or right, such as:

```
margin-right: 20px;
```

Comment: Hi Dalal - thanks for being a part of StackOverflow, and offering your help! May I suggest you read [answer], and also - do not post multiple answers like this.  These really should be comments - I know you don't yet have the rep to add comments, but you will soon....

Answer (score 0):

Position  before the button you want to make an equal distance between it and the remaining buttons and then define it within the stayle setting the distance you want between each button and Use the  command and select the direction you want to set the distance between and the other button if left or right, such as

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 44px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #323232;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #B8B8B8;
}

.appleNav {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="appleNav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/apple-xxl.png" height="20"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/search-3-xxl.png" height="20"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">User</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer, explaining the code you post.

Answer (score -3):

Here's their code in this code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRKjzz

```
<nav id="ac-globalnav" class="js no-touch" role="navigation" aria-label="Global" data-hires="false" data-analytics-region="global nav" lang="en-US" dir="ltr" data-store-locale="us" data-store-api="/[storefront]/shop/bag/status" data-search-locale="en_US" data-search-api="/search-services/suggestions/">
<div class="ac-gn-content">
    <ul class="ac-gn-header">
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-menuicon">
            <label class="ac-gn-menuicon-label" for="ac-gn-menustate" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="ac-gn-menuicon-bread ac-gn-menuicon-bread-top">
                    <span class="ac-gn-menuicon-bread-crust ac-gn-menuicon-bread-crust-top"></span>
                </span>
                <span class="ac-gn-menuicon-bread ac-gn-menuicon-bread-bottom">
                    <span class="ac-gn-menuicon-bread-crust ac-gn-menuicon-bread-crust-bottom"></span>
                </span>
            </label>
            <a href="#ac-gn-menustate" class="ac-gn-menuanchor ac-gn-menuanchor-open" id="ac-gn-menuanchor-open">
                <span class="ac-gn-menuanchor-label">Open Menu</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="ac-gn-menuanchor ac-gn-menuanchor-close" id="ac-gn-menuanchor-close">
                <span class="ac-gn-menuanchor-label">Close Menu</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-apple">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-apple" href="/" data-analytics-title="apple home" id="ac-gn-firstfocus-small">
                <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Apple</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-bag ac-gn-bag-small" id="ac-gn-bag-small">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-bag" href="/us/shop/goto/bag" data-analytics-title="bag" data-analytics-click="bag" aria-label="Shopping Bag" data-string-badge="Shopping Bag with Items" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ac-gn-bagview-content">
                <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Shopping Bag</span>
                <span class="ac-gn-bag-badge"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="ac-gn-bagview-caret ac-gn-bagview-caret-large"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ac-gn-search-placeholder-container" role="search">
        <div class="ac-gn-search ac-gn-search-small">
            <a id="ac-gn-link-search-small" class="ac-gn-link" href="/us/search" data-analytics-title="search" data-analytics-click="search" data-analytics-intrapage-link="" aria-label="Search apple.com" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">
                <div class="ac-gn-search-placeholder-bar">
                    <div class="ac-gn-search-placeholder-input">
                        <div class="ac-gn-search-placeholder-input-text" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="ac-gn-link-search ac-gn-search-placeholder-input-icon"></div>
                            <span class="ac-gn-search-placeholder">Search apple.com</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ac-gn-searchview-close ac-gn-searchview-close-small ac-gn-search-placeholder-searchview-close">
                        <span class="ac-gn-searchview-close-cancel" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ac-gn-list">
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-apple">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-apple" href="/" data-analytics-title="apple home" id="ac-gn-firstfocus">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Apple</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-mac">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-mac" href="/mac/" data-analytics-title="mac">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Mac</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-ipad">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-ipad" href="/ipad/" data-analytics-title="ipad">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">iPad</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-iphone">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-iphone" href="/iphone/" data-analytics-title="iphone">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">iPhone</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-watch">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-watch" href="/watch/" data-analytics-title="watch">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Watch</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-tv">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-tv" href="/tv/" data-analytics-title="tv">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">TV</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-music">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-music" href="/music/" data-analytics-title="music">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Music</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-support">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-support" href="https://support.apple.com" data-analytics-title="support">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Support</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-search" role="search">
            <a id="ac-gn-link-search" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-search" href="/us/search" data-analytics-title="search" data-analytics-click="search" data-analytics-intrapage-link="" aria-label="Search apple.com" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-bag" id="ac-gn-bag">
            <a class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-bag" href="/us/shop/goto/bag" data-analytics-title="bag" data-analytics-click="bag" aria-label="Shopping Bag" data-string-badge="Shopping Bag with Items" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ac-gn-bagview-content">
                    <span class="ac-gn-link-text">Shopping Bag</span>
                    <span class="ac-gn-bag-badge" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            <span class="ac-gn-bagview-caret ac-gn-bagview-caret-large"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <aside id="ac-gn-searchview" class="ac-gn-searchview" role="search" data-analytics-region="search">
        <div class="ac-gn-searchview-content">
            <div class="ac-gn-searchview-bar">
                <div class="ac-gn-searchview-bar-wrapper">
                    <form id="ac-gn-searchform" class="ac-gn-searchform" action="/us/search" method="get">
                        <div class="ac-gn-searchform-wrapper">
                            <input id="ac-gn-searchform-input" class="ac-gn-searchform-input" type="text" aria-label="Search apple.com" placeholder="Search apple.com" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
                            <input id="ac-gn-searchform-src" type="hidden" name="src" value="globalnav">
                            <button id="ac-gn-searchform-submit" class="ac-gn-searchform-submit" type="submit" disabled="" aria-label="Submit Search"></button>
                            <button id="ac-gn-searchform-reset" class="ac-gn-searchform-reset" type="reset" disabled="" aria-label="Clear Search">
                                    <span class="ac-gn-searchform-reset-background"></span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <button id="ac-gn-searchview-close-small" class="ac-gn-searchview-close ac-gn-searchview-close-small" aria-label="Cancel Search">
                            <span class="ac-gn-searchview-close-cancel" aria-hidden="true">
                                Cancel
                            </span>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <aside id="ac-gn-searchresults" class="ac-gn-searchresults" data-string-quicklinks="Quick Links" data-string-suggestions="Suggested Searches" data-string-noresults=""> <section class="ac-gn-searchresults-section ac-gn-searchresults-section-defaultlinks" data-analytics-region="defaultlinks search">
    <div class="ac-gn-searchresults-section-wrapper">
        <h3 class="ac-gn-searchresults-header ac-gn-searchresults-animated">Quick Links</h3>
        <ul class="ac-gn-searchresults-list">
            <li class="ac-gn-searchresults-item ac-gn-searchresults-animated">
                <a href="https://www.apple.com/retail/" class="ac-gn-searchresults-link ac-gn-searchresults-link-defaultlinks" data-query="no keyword" data-section="defaultlinks" data-items="5" data-index="0" data-label="Find a Store" data-analytics-click="eVar23: {data-query} | {data-section} | {data-items} | {data-label} | {data-index}, events:event50">Find a Store</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ac-gn-searchresults-item ac-gn-searchresults-animated">
                <a href="https://www.apple.com/us/shop/goto/accessories/apple_accessories" class="ac-gn-searchresults-link ac-gn-searchresults-link-defaultlinks" data-query="no keyword" data-section="defaultlinks" data-items="5" data-index="1" data-label="Accessories" data-analytics-click="eVar23: {data-query} | {data-section} | {data-items} | {data-label} | {data-index}, events:event50">Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ac-gn-searchresults-item ac-gn-searchresults-animated">
                <a href="https://www.apple.com/ipod/" class="ac-gn-searchresults-link ac-gn-searchresults-link-defaultlinks" data-query="no keyword" data-section="defaultlinks" data-items="5" data-index="2" data-label="iPod" data-analytics-click="eVar23: {data-query} | {data-section} | {data-items} | {data-label} | {data-index}, events:event50">iPod</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ac-gn-searchresults-item ac-gn-searchresults-animated">
                <a href="https://www.apple.com/ios/" class="ac-gn-searchresults-link ac-gn-searchresults-link-defaultlinks" data-query="no keyword" data-section="defaultlinks" data-items="5" data-index="3" data-label="iOS" data-analytics-click="eVar23: {data-query} | {data-section} | {data-items} | {data-label} | {data-index}, events:event50">iOS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ac-gn-searchresults-item ac-gn-searchresults-animated">
                <a href="https://www.apple.com/us/shop/goto/giftcards" class="ac-gn-searchresults-link ac-gn-searchresults-link-defaultlinks" data-query="no keyword" data-section="defaultlinks" data-items="5" data-index="4" data-label="Gift Cards" data-analytics-click="eVar23: {data-query} | {data-section} | {data-items} | {data-label} | {data-index}, events:event50">Gift Cards</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS is too big to include here.